# Sitecore 8.1: Layout Switcher disabled

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I'm using Sitecore.NET 8.1 (rev. 160302), Everything seems to work fine but the Layout Switcher ribbon in experience editor mode is disabled. There is no client error or server error.

[image: Disabed Layout Switcher]

The application was updated from Sitecore 8 to 8.1.

Comment: Is this using an admin account or only for certain users? Makes sure the user is a member of the `Sitecore Client Designing`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is a multi-site solution, [this](http://ggullentops.blogspot.be/2015/11/previewresolvesite-and-disabled-shared.html) blog post states that setting `Preview.ResolveSite` to `true` from within the `Sitecore.config` settings file will resolve the problem. If this property doesn't exist there, your SLN may have a patch for Sitecore settings elsewhere under /App_Config/Include.

I recently set up an 8.1 instance that had this setting set to `false` by default.

Answer (score 0):

Also, set "SiteResolvingMatchCurrentLanguage" to false for multi-lingual sites where the content editor is using a different language than the site's language. If the sc_site parameter contains the wrong site, the layout buttons get disabled.